# Detecting errors when connecting to a backplane in SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, redis, signalr, signalr-backplane

Is there a way to detect if a signaR hub fails to connect to a given backplane (either SQL or REDIS). For example, given a bad connection string or unable to reach the backplane server?

Here's my simplified startup class:

```
public class Startup
{

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var backplaneType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SignalR.BackplaneType"];

    if (backplaneType == "SQL")
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SignalR.SQL"].ConnectionString;
        var sqlScaleoutConfig = new SqlScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlScaleoutConfig);

    }
    else if(backplaneType == "Redis")
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SignalR.Redis"].ConnectionString;
        var config = new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, "SomeKey");
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(config);
    }

    app.MapSignalR();
}
}
```

this is so that we can log any errors and also make note of it in our APM software.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I think its a great idea to do this.